# lifting functions in python

Tags: python, function, set, python-3.6

Say you have a function `f:integers -> integers`, one should be able to lift this function to act on sets of integers.

I.e. `f:sets of integers -> sets of integers`, by `f({a,b,...}) = {f(a),f(b),...}`

How can one do this succinctly in python? That is, not involving iterables (loops), potentially something more native and order-independent.

I would expect `f({a,b,...})` to be the syntax, but it's not. Maybe something like `act(f,{a,b,...})`?

Comment: you mean set comprehension? `print({f(x) for x in {1,2,3}})` or `set(map(f,{1,2,3}))`

Comment: note that sets are unordered so order of the result may not match order of the input.

Comment: There's no way to do this without involving iteration. Sure, you can `map` it but, that's iteration too. You're probably after `map`, though.

Comment: Sweet, Jean's answer is what I was looking for.


>There's no way to do with without involving iteration


So I might be naive, but if one were able to compute on a GPU, would this "map" function still be iterable, or would the computations be done in parallel?

Comment: you need `multiprocessing.map` then

Comment: or for GPU pyCUDA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957574/python-rewrite-a-looping-numpy-math-function-to-run-on-gpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python 2.7.10**

What you described is mapping; it does involve loops in the background, but it achieves your succinctness. Here's an example.

```
l = [1,2,3]   

#f returns n^2
def f(n):
    return n*n

l = map(f, l) #[1,4,9]
```

`map` applies the function `f` to every element of `l`.

`map` also works on sets; however, map returns back a list of values e.g. `f({x1,x2,x3}) = [f(x1),f(x2),f(x3)]`, in an arbitrary order. You can turn the returned list back into a set by wrapping it as a `set`.

**Python 3.6**

In Python 3.6, `map` returns back a map object, and you will need to convert it to your desired typed. This example shows the map object converted to a list.

```
l = [1,2,3]
def f(n):
    return n*n
l = list(map(f, l)) #[1,4,9]
```

Alternatively, you can reduce the amount of code further using lambda functions, making it more succinct.

```
l = [1,2,3]
l = map(lambda x:x*x, l)
```

Where the lambda expression has the functionality `f` but used only there and non-existent afterwards.

Comment: Note that the behavior you display is Python 2 only, you need to wrap it in `list`.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Good call! Let me update it my answer to show the 3.6 behavior.

Comment: the issue with sets is undefined ordering. there's no way to associate inputs & outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The tools you want are [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), and in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

For example, to apply `f` on a collection `c` of elements, you can use

```
map(f, c)
```

Note that the application is lazy in Python 3, and eager in Python 2.7. Alternatively, you can also use a lazy comprehension:

```
g(f(x) for x in c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple arguments as well , like this:

```
def square(*args) :
    l = []
    for i in args:
        l.append(i**2)
    return l
```

It'll return like:

```
>>>> square(1,2,3,4)
>>>> [1,2,9,16]
>>>> square(1)
>>>> [1]
>>>> square(1,6)
>>>> [1,36]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python currying is not a native feature but you can emulate it using `functools.partial`. For instance, you can use `partial` to lift a function `f: A -> B` to a function `f': [A] -> [B]`.

```
from functools import partial
def f(...):
    ...

# lift f
f_lifted = partial(map, f)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from funcy import curry



def lift(fn):
    return curry(map)(fn)
```