# Efficient tensor contraction in python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-einsum

I have a list `L` of tensors (`ndarray` objects), with several indices each. I need to contract these indices according to a graph of connections.

The connections are encoded in a list of tuples in the form `((m,i),(n,j))` signifying "contract the *i*-th index of the tensor `L[m]` with the *j*-th index of the tensor `L[n]`.

How can I handle non-trivial connectivity graphs? The first problem is that as soon as I contract a pair of indices, the result is a new tensor that does not belong to the list `L`. But even if I solved this (e.g. by giving a unique identifier to all the indices of all the tensors), there is the issue that one can pick any order to perform the contractions, and some choices yield unnecessarily enormous beasts in mid-computation (even if the final result is small). Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory considerations aside, I believe you can do the contractions in a single call to `einsum`, although you'll need some preprocessing. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "*as I contract a pair of indices, the result is a new tensor that does not belong to the list `L`*", but I think doing the contraction in a single step would exactly solve this problem.

I suggest using the alternative, numerically indexed syntax of [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
einsum(op0, sublist0, op1, sublist1, ..., [sublistout])
```

So what you need to do is encode the indices to contract in integer sequences. First you'll need to set up a range of unique indices initially, and keep another copy to be used as `sublistout`. Then, iterating over your connectivity graph, you need to set contracted indices to the same index where necessary, and at the same time remove the contracted index from `sublistout`.

```
import numpy as np

def contract_all(tensors,conns):
    '''
    Contract the tensors inside the list tensors
    according to the connectivities in conns

    Example input:
    tensors = [np.random.rand(2,3),np.random.rand(3,4,5),np.random.rand(3,4)]
    conns = [((0,1),(2,0)), ((1,1),(2,1))]
    returned shape in this case is (2,3,5)
    '''

    ndims = [t.ndim for t in tensors]
    totdims = sum(ndims)
    dims0 = np.arange(totdims)
    # keep track of sublistout throughout
    sublistout = set(dims0.tolist())
    # cut up the index array according to tensors
    # (throw away empty list at the end)
    inds = np.split(dims0,np.cumsum(ndims))[:-1]
    # we also need to convert to a list, otherwise einsum chokes
    inds = [ind.tolist() for ind in inds]

    # if there were no contractions, we'd call
    # np.einsum(*zip(tensors,inds),sublistout)

    # instead we need to loop over the connectivity graph
    # and manipulate the indices
    for (m,i),(n,j) in conns:
        # tensors[m][i] contracted with tensors[n][j]

        # remove the old indices from sublistout which is a set
        sublistout -= {inds[m][i],inds[n][j]}

        # contract the indices
        inds[n][j] = inds[m][i]

    # zip and flatten the tensors and indices
    args = [subarg for arg in zip(tensors,inds) for subarg in arg]

    # assuming there are no multiple contractions, we're done here
    return np.einsum(*args,sublistout)
```

A trivial example:

```
>>> tensors = [np.random.rand(2,3), np.random.rand(4,3)]
>>> conns = [((0,1),(1,1))]
>>> contract_all(tensors,conns)
array([[ 1.51970003,  1.06482209,  1.61478989,  1.86329518],
       [ 1.16334367,  0.60125945,  1.00275992,  1.43578448]])
>>> np.einsum('ij,kj',tensors[0],tensors[1])
array([[ 1.51970003,  1.06482209,  1.61478989,  1.86329518],
       [ 1.16334367,  0.60125945,  1.00275992,  1.43578448]])
```

In case there are multiple contractions, the logistics in the loop becomes a bit more complex, because we need to handle all the duplicates. The logic, however, is the same. Furthermore, the above is obviously missing checks to ensure that the corresponding indices *can* be contracted.

In hindsight I realized that the default `sublistout` doesn't have to be specified, `einsum` uses that order anyway. I decided to leave that variable in the code, because in case we want a non-trivial output index order, we'll have to handle that variable appropriately, and it might come handy.

---

As for optimization of the contraction order, you can effect internal optimization in `np.einsum` as of version 1.12 (as noted by @hpaulj in a now-deleted comment). This version introduced the `optimize` optional keyword argument to `np.einsum`, allowing to choose a contraction order that cuts down on computational time at the cost of memory. Passing `'greedy'` or `'optimal'` as the `optimize` keyword will make numpy choose a contraction order in roughly decreasing order of sizes of the dimensions.

The options available for the `optimize` keyword come from the apparently undocumented (as far as online documentation goes; `help()` fortunately works) function `np.einsum_path`:

```
einsum_path(subscripts, *operands, optimize='greedy')

Evaluates the lowest cost contraction order for an einsum expression by
considering the creation of intermediate arrays.
```

The output contraction path from `np.einsum_path` can also be used as an input for the `optimize` argument of `np.einsum`. In your question you were worried about too much memory being used, so I suspect that the default of no optimization (with potentially longer runtime and smaller memory footprint).

Comment: @hpaulj even in [the version-specific docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) I can only see the mention of `np.einsum_path`, but no link... Thanks for the `optimize` tip, I completely missed that (even though I have 1.12)!

Comment: @hpaulj that figures:) I only revert to that when I know the function I'm looking for...

Comment: In a recent SO question I found that `optimize='optimal'` let me calculate a larger `einsum` array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942115/numpy-efficient-large-dot-products.  So far that's my only experience with the new features.

Comment: That's great, I'll try this out over the weekend! By the way, today I wrote a function that computes the best (memory-wise) contraction order, so that's covered.

Comment: @Ziofil I'm looking forward to your findings:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak, by 'multiple contractions' do you mean contracting an index in more than two tensors? If so, this is never the case for my application.

Comment: @Ziofil exactly, that's what I meant. I suspected that this isn't the case, but I wanted to note this assumption explicitly to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I can tell einsum in which order to perform the contractions. For this I could use the output of np.einsum_path, or I could have the output of the optimization function that I wrote myself to have the same format. I'll compare them.

Comment: @Ziofil I think so, yes. I've never used these optimization options of einsum, so I don't have any experience. hpaulj's link above shows a case where optimization allowed him to perform a contraction that would not run with optimizations disabled. I would expect, however, `einsum`'s `optimize` keyword to do the same as if fed with the output of `einsum_path`. Then again this could be checked too for your specific case...

Comment: Woah! With `optimization=True` I get about 1000x improvement in the first realistic examples!

Comment: yeah, I meant `optimize=True`, I cannot edit the comment anymore. Thank you so much btw!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe helpful: Take a look into https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0939 which is a description of an efficient framework for the problem of contracting so called tensor networks in a single function `ncon(...)`. As far as I see implementations of it are directly available for Matlab (can be found within in the link) and for Python3 (https://github.com/mhauru/ncon).